# Find coordinates vector

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

$S = \{t^3+t^2, t^2+t, t+1, 1\}$ is a basis of $P_3(t)$. Find the coordinate vector $[v]$ of $v$ relative to $S$ where:

(a) $\quad v = 2t^3+t^2-4t+2$

(b) $\quad v = at^3+bt^2+ct+d$

I'm finding, for (a), that the coordinate vector
$$
[v] = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ -3 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}, 
$$
but the answer in Seymour Lipschutz's *Linear Algebra* book is
$$
[v] = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

For this question, I found that
$$
at^3 + (a+b)t^2 + (b+c)t + (c+d) 
= 2t^3 + t^2 - 4t + 2.
$$
So, $a = 2$, then $b = -1$, $c = -3$, and $d = 5$. What did I do wrong??

And for part (b), I'm finding that
$$
[v] = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a \\ 
b - a \\ 
c - b + a \\ 
d - c + b - a 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
but the answer in the same book is
$$
[v] = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a \\ 
b - c \\
c - b + a \\ 
d - c + b - a 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
with the difference being only the $b-a$ to $b-c$. Is the book wrong? Please help me, I'm stuck :(

Comment: Your two answers are correct.

Comment: It's always much easier to verify your coordinates than it is to find them in the first place. Just expand the linear combination of the basis with weights from your coordinate vector.